# Artifacts in Managed DirectX 9 - any idea?

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-9

I have this artifacts when drawing meshes (box, cylinders) but also at intersections of trianglelists. Any idea?

[image: crazy artifacts]

Comment: Looks like a bad projection matrix, loss of Z-buffer precision. How do you calculate your projection matrix?

Comment: simple PerspectiveFovLH() with field of view 0.3f, aspect ratio 1.0f nearplane 1.0f farplane 1000.0f. when i use 100 as farplane i see nothing - with 10000 its the same...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your objects are positioned quite far from the camera, at distance about 900-1000, and that you have 16-bit Z-buffer. Try increasing nearplane, for example, set nearplane=100. Generally it is recommended to try to keep the farplane/nearplane ratio as low as possible, depending on your  scene geometry.

Comment: ok, i will try that. When i change the z-buffer to 32bit my application doesnt start:-(